# Magento 2: Set value of Yes/No custom attribute programmatically

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes

I created a custom `Yes/No` attribute for products and assigned it to `default` attribute group. I have to save value of `Yes/No` attribute programmatically. 
is it possible? if Yes, How can I manage product value programmatically?

Answer (score 3):

Use this if you dont want to save the whole product. Its much faster.

```
$productObj->setData('attribute_code', 1); //$value = 1 for yes and $value = 0 for No.
$productObj->getResource()->saveAttribute($productObj, 'attribute_code');
```

Comment: Thanks kingshuk, Do you have any idea of getData from custom attribute ?

Comment: `$productObj->getAttributeCode();` Do you mean this?

Comment: Let me check this one

Comment: not its not working for me, i am not able to get attribute like this.

Comment: Probably that attribute has no value assigned yet. Either set it to YES or No then save the product and check on frontend. You should be able to get it.

Comment: $_product = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId); $attrivuteValue =$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_CODE')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
 - Here is how I got my result?  Thanks for you help.

Comment: How to use same code for customer custom attributes?

Answer (score 1):

You can set it like:

`$prodcut->setAttributeName(1);`

`$prodcut->save();`